# Constructing HTML in Controller - how to refactor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm currently generating breadcrumbs on an object's Details page by calling a GetBreadcrumbs() method in the object's controller - in this method, the object's parent/grandparent are used to generate an unordered list.  What's the best way to pull the HTML out of the controller to follow the Separation of Concerns paradigm?  Should a partial view be used here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typical example of partial view is Breadcrum itself. For example, in your controller you can have

```
//
//GET: News/Article/x
public ActionResult Article(int id)
{
    //get parentid of article
    ViewBag.id = id;
    ViewBag.parentid;
    return View();
}
```

So, your partial view will be as below:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Article";
}

<h2>Viewing Article @ViewBag.parentid >> @ViewBag.id</h2>
```

Comment: Thank you.  What if an Article has a parent Article, which may or may not have a parent Article, etc etc?  Where would this logic of looping through the parents belong?

Answer (score 0):

You could use partial views or display templates. Your controller should only build the model that will be passed to the view and then inside the view you could use a display template that will build the desired output based on the model.

Comment: Should this model (that I'm passing to the view) also include all of the parent objects that are required to build the breadcrumbs?